# c# webclient download data from url with extension

Tags: c#

Im trying to download data from yahoo finance http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X  but it downloads from http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/. Ive been searching around and can remember seeing download data has a problem with extensions? is there any solution for this?

current code

```
WebClient eurusdclient = new WebClient();

eurusdclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", 
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

string eurusdcode = eurusdclient
    .DownloadString(string.Format("http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X"));
```

Thanks all :)

Comment: What do you mean by "extension" here? And why are you using string.Format without anything to format? The code you've given seems to download a reasonable string...

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebClient's QueryString property

> The QueryString property contains a NameValueCollection instance containing name/value pairs that are appended to the URI as a query string. The contents of the QueryString property are preceded by a question mark (?), and name/value pairs are separated from one another by an ampersand (&).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.querystring.aspx

That allows you to specify a number of name/value pairs that will be used in the query string for the request.